# How can i identify variation in distinct values of column from last 3 days

Tags: python, mysql, excel

The use case is,
I have to identify buggy columns from sql table, Buggy columns -  with sudden increase or decrease in count,

Let suppose there is column `flag` with count on following days are

```
09/02/2020  10/02/2020 11/02/2020
10           10         100
```

On 11 Feb there is increase in column values so i have to identify these type of columns from table 
So is there any tool to identify such columns.(preferable in python)

Comment: If you have columns named after dates then you have far larger problems to address. If I've misunderstood, then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can check the percentage changes:

```
df.pct_change(axis='columns')

   09/02/2020  10/02/2020  11/02/2020
0         NaN         0.0         9.0
```